# Modelling a couch cushion with complex seams

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

i need your expertise, as I'am struggling with a workflow for creating this pattern on the upper side of the cushion. I followed some tutorials for chesterfield sofas, however the workflow won't apply perfectly to my demand.

Here are some more images: https://www.boconcept.com/de-de/clp/osaka-sofa

Thankful for every advice.
Marco

[image]

---

thanks for your input.

By using the cloth simulation I faced some difficulties to make the edges harder. I used the subsurface modifier instead to create the shape of the seat cushion and used the bevel tool to create the sharp edges.

The result looked like this, however, I still need to add more detail and work on the texture for a more realistic render.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

1-

[image]

2-

[image]

3-bevel the middle loops

[image]

4-Hit [ctrl -] and shift H to isolate the middle loops

[image]

5-press alt S and shrink the selected edges a bit, then select the center vertex and move it down with proportional editing

[image]

6-select these vertices and move them up

[image]

7-add subd modifier and finalize your mesh

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You could use a cloth simulation and a pin group:

[image]

I pinned 4 corner + 1 crossing vertices with 100% weight (`1`), and lines joining them with 50% weight. High Pressure and additional Subdivision Surface.

[image]

Comment: +1 Great solution! Only that you needed 5 crossing vertices set to 1, because in real cushions there have to be buttons at each end of a line otherwise the line would not be there correctly.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann so the simulation is wrong? :P

Comment: Yes sure, because real cushions have no 50% weight on the lines ;) The problem with your version vs. a real cushion is: how you get the lines from the center to the sides if you have no buttons (in this scenario weight = 100%) there? Why do they not simply go the corners? And why do they stop at the border when there is no button? Well, I know there are seams to guide those lines, but still those cushions have buttons on each crossing. As I said, great solution - you just forgot some buttons.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You're right, I was being provocative. As it works currently is that there are rigidly attached points, and points attached with rubbers. Not actually realistic. Without the lines this happens: https://i.imgur.com/goMHQ1x.png