How to deform button pattern around curved bench
I am trying to model a simple version of a "banquette". Something like this:

I have started by making the curved part by extruding a plane, and just adding a bevel modifier for the corner and then solidify modifier. I have also made a very simplifed version of the button pattern:

I would now like to make this array pattern fit onto the front surface of the bench, but had little success with any of the obvious modifiers (Shrinkwrap, Surface Deform, or Simple Deform). Can anyone suggest how I might go about doing this?
Thanks

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306353/modelling-a-couch-cushion-with-complex-seams https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19241/model-upholstery-with-buttons

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks, these are useful links. However, they are more about how to make an intricate and realistic button pattern. My concern is more about the high level shape, i.e. assuming we have a nice button pattern (a task for another day), how do we make it into the curved global bench shape?

Curve modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95978/how-can-i-model-an-irregular-object-made-from-laser-cutting-metal-sheet/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49639/how-to-smooth-an-arrayed-object-so-the-breaks-between-objects-are-less-obvious/49651#49651

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos So I need to somehow convert only one edge of the bench into a curve, and then map the pattern onto that? Can you provide example?

Both those answers have examples you can follow along. Just create a curve object roughly following the shape of you couch, then array a single module to fill the length of that curve and deform it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier/65571#65571 for all the known caveats

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes I know what you mean. The issue is that I want to manipulate the dimensions of the couch base, and then have the buttons follow with it. Ideally I don't want an intermediate object (your  curve) which is only "roughly" the same shape, and which i need to also adjust if I adjust the couch dimensions. Does it make sense?

I believe you are thinking about it the wrong way.
The curve would be your actual couch, in such way that it would control its shape, rather than something you would have to keep updated manually.


Make a single tufted couch module.
Optionally make bespoke end caps for the array
Array it to fit a bezier curve
Add a curve modifier afterwards to make it follow the curve



May I ask how you capture your gifs ? I'd like to do the same. Thank you !

@Lutzi See https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/ I use ScreenToGIF

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ah I see, this is a quite different approach to what I had in mind. Looks good! Could you share the blend file so I can play with it?

Sorry I don't have  one, I never saved it
